# How best to Impersonate a user account on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

I've a Java program that is copying a file from Unix to hdfs. It is running fine however I am looking for impersonating a different account when it runs and copies file.

Input: Apart form input file and target hdfs directory path, another input should be properties file containing account, keytab directory, domain

Please kindly let me know the best way to move forward.

I am currently exploring using a shell to first issue a kinit command and then run the jar

I am also reading about Jaas and how this can be done in Java itself - from - https://henning.kropponline.de/2016/02/14/a-secure-hdfs-client-example/

Need inputs and any reference of available options.

My Java program that copies file is as below:

```
public class FileCopy implements Runnable {

@Option(names = {"-i","--input"}, required=true, description="file name to copy to hadoop")
String input;

@Option(names = {"-o","--output"}, required=true, description="hdfs directory path to be copied into")
String output;


public void run() {


    Properties hadoop_properties = new Properties();
    HdfsFileDeploy hdfsFileDeploy = new HdfsFileDeploy();

    try {
        hadoop_properties.load(FileCopy.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hadoop.properties"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    FileSystem fs = hdfsFileDeploy.configureFilesystem(hadoop_properties.getProperty("coreSitePath"),hadoop_properties.getProperty("hdfsSitePath"));


    String status = hdfsFileDeploy.writeToHDFS(fs,input,output);

    if (status == "SUCCESS") {
            System.out.println("completed copying");
    } else {
        System.out.println("copying error");
    }

    hdfsFileDeploy.closeFileSystem(fs);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    CommandLine.run(new FileCopy(), args);

}
```

}

public class HdfsFileDeploy {

```
   public FileSystem configureFilesystem(String coreSitePath, String hdfsSitePath) {

        FileSystem fileSystem = null;

        try {

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            Path hdfsCoreSitePath = new Path(coreSitePath);
            Path hdfsHDFSSitePath = new Path(hdfsSitePath);
            conf.addResource(hdfsCoreSitePath);
            conf.addResource(hdfsHDFSSitePath);


            fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
            System.out.println(fileSystem);
            return fileSystem;

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
            return fileSystem;
        }
    }


   public void closeFileSystem(FileSystem fileSystem) {

        try {
            fileSystem.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to close Hadoop filesystem : " + ex);

        }
   }

   // 

    public String writeToHDFS(FileSystem fileSystem, String sourcePath, String destinationPath) {

        String failure = "FAILURE";
        String success = "SUCCESS";
        Boolean doNotDelSrc = false;
        Boolean overwrite = true;

        try {
            Path inputPath = new Path(sourcePath);
            Path outputPath = new Path(destinationPath);

            if(!fileSystem.exists(outputPath)) {
                System.out.println("Output path " + outputPath + " does not exist. Creating outputPath directory now..");
                if (fileSystem.mkdirs(outputPath)) {
                    System.out.println("Output path " + outputPath + " created...");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("about to copy from " + inputPath + " to " + outputPath);
            fileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(doNotDelSrc, overwrite, inputPath, outputPath);
            return success;

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println("Some exception occurred while writing file to hdfs");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return failure;
        }
    }
```

}

Input1: input file 
Input2: target hdfs directory
Reference Input: file (say yaml) containing account, domain, keytab path.

jar should impersonate and copy the input file to target hdfs directory.

Comment: _"It is running fine however I am looking for impersonating a different account "_ > what does that mean? It seems you have Kerberos authentication in Hadoop ; so where do you get your Kerberos credentials (TGT) currently?

Comment: Did you do any research? If yes, did you not stumble on the `UserGroupInformation` static object which is a (lame) Hadoop wrapper around the (lame) Java implementation of Kerberos?

Comment: For the record, without Kerberos, "impersonation" simply means setting an env variable.